# Add a popup to a Vector LineString in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, vector

Is it possible to add a popup (without a marker icon) to a Vector (LineString)?

This is my code, if possible, how to change it to add the popup? I need the popup to display some additional information to the road segement.

```
<script>
var ytrajectory=[];
ytrajectory.push('LINESTRING (11.1119339 46.0772706, 11.1117177 46.077171, 11.111613 46.0770837, 11.1115376 46.07702)');
ytrajectory.push('LINESTRING (11.1115376 46.07702, 11.1114585 46.0768611, 11.1114219 46.0767673)');

...
</script>
function showReconstructedTrajectoryy() {
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
"Reconstructed trajectoryy", {
style : reconstructedTrajectoryStyleYellow
});

var parser = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();
var src = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');
var dest = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');

var s, wktLine, features, reprojectedFeatures;
for (s = 0; s < ytrajectory.length; s++) {
wktLine = ytrajectory[s];
features = parser.read(wktLine);
reprojectedFeatures = features.geometry.transform(src, dest);
vectorLayer.addFeatures(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
reprojectedFeatures));
}

osmmap.addLayer(vectorLayer);
osmmap.zoomToExtent(vectorLayer.getDataExtent());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to add a control to select the feature:

```
 select: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
                vectorlayer,
                {
                    clickout: false, toggle: false,
                    multiple: false, hover: false,
                    toggleKey: "ctrlKey", // ctrl key removes from selection
                    multipleKey: "shiftKey", // shift key adds to selection
                    box: true
                }
```

then you need to add an event listener for the layer selection and set the popup to appear:

```
function onFeatureSelect(event) {
        popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken", 
                                 feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                                 new OpenLayers.Size(100,100),
                                 content,
                                 null, true, onPopupClose);
        feature.popup = popup;
        map.addPopup(popup);
         }
```